# Are each variations of a .resx file supposed to generate their own Designer.cs file?

Tags: c#, code-generation, rider, resx

I haven't been able to find much about how `.Designer.cs` files work in relations to `.resx` files in the official docs, and Googling for this kind of situation hasn't resulted in any useful information.

---

The project I'm currently working on needs to support multiple languages. As such, it has localization files:

- Localization.resx
- Localization.en.resx
- Validation.resx
- Validation.en.resx

*Note: English isn't the default language.*

I noticed that, along with the `.resx` files, we have some `Designer.cs` files. Specifically, we have the following ones:

- Localization.Designer.cs
- Localization.en.Designer.cs
- Validation.Designer.cs

For some reason, `Validation.en.resx` does not have a corresponding `.en.Designer.cs` file.

If we make modifications to the `.en.resx` file, a designer file isn't generated for it. Those changes still work, though. Going on our site and setting the culture to English shows the English values. Looking at our Git status, there doesn't appear to be an `.en.Designer.cs` file somewhere else, and it isn't ignored by our `.gitignore` file.

To generate a `Validation.en.Designer.cs` file, I've tried:

- Disabling code generation and re-enabling it as public
- Using VS2022 with the "Run Custom Tool" action
- Using Rider with the "Generate Resources" action
- Creating blank `.resx`/`.en.resx` files and manually move the values inside of it
- Updating the `.csproj` file manually to make sure it has the same ResX code as the other files

The only thing that's worked was to create an empty `Validator.en.Designer.cs` file, which instantly got populated with the correct values.

However, when team members make changes to the `.en.resx` file, the `.en.Designer` file isn't updated, even though their changes work when compiling/running the app. Changes to the default `.resx` files *do* result in changes to the `.Designer.cs` file, though.

So are we *supposed* to have an `.en.Designer.cs` file alongside our `.en.resx` file? Or is the default `.Designer.cs` file supposed to handle picking the correct `.resx` source based on local and we just have extra files in our project?

Comment: I've tried with both `ResXFileCodeGenerator` and `PublicResXFileCodeGenerator`. The Build Action is set to "Embedded resource"

Comment: Odd. I can reproduce this in 2019 if I create a new resx file with an extra `.en` in the file name. I notice upon creation it does not have anything filled in for Custom Tool and there is no Designer file. Setting it to `ResXFileCodeGenerator` automatically generates the file for me. Edit: Ah, I see. For me it also doesn't update when I save.

Comment: Do you know if the `.en.Designer.cs` file is usually required for it to work? It appears to work for me, but everything I've read online seems to imply that it shoulnd't.

Comment: For me in 2019 it just generates bad code (it doesn't pick up anything in an existing resource file either). I think it might have trouble resolving the `.` in the file name to a valid class name in C#. Are you able to rename the file? Something like `Validation_EN`?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I can suffix it with an `_en`, but then the localization doesn't work anymore. Which lines up with what I've seen in the docs (it always mentions `the .en.resx` format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is, no, there is no Designer file for each localized resource file.

The C# file does not actually hold the `Value` part of the resx file. It instead generates code to look up values in the resource files, this includes code for culture-dependent lookups as well. You can see this in the Designer file generated by the main resx file, there is a section of the C# code that says (reformatted for brevity):

```cs
public static global::System.Globalization.CultureInfo Culture {
    get { return resourceCulture; }
    set { resourceCulture = value; }
}
```

This means that there is built-in support for localization, so when you set your culture:

```
Resources.Validation.Culture = new CultureInfo("en");
```

...then reference the localized string later (using `Greeting` as an example):

```
Console.WriteLine(Resources.Validation.Greeting);
```

...it will automatically select the proper resource. If no string is found, it will default to the main resx file.

### Example

Let's say you have three resource files:

- Main one: **Validation.resx**, contains (`Anatid`, `Duck-translation here`)
- English: **Validation.en.resx**, contains (`Anatid`, `Duck`)
- Japanese: **Validation.ja-JP.resx**, contains (`Anatid`, `カモ`)

To use them:

```cs
foreach (string loc in new[] { "en", "ja-JP", "sr-Cyrl-RS" })
{
    Resources.Validation.Culture = new CultureInfo(loc);
    Console.WriteLine(Resources.Validation.Anatid);
}
/* Outputs:
Duck
カモ (Or ??. `chcp 932` if you really want to see katakana. Point is, it looks up the value.)
Duck-translation here
*/
```

---

For additional functionality, you can follow directions listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/localization), but it may be more than you need to do.

Comment: It seems our confusion was due to Rider automatically generating a `.en.Designer.cs` file if we created a new `.resx` file by right-clicking on the folder. The "proper" way of doing it in rider is through the Localization Manager window, which won't create a Designer file. We ended-up with some extra Designer files at some point, and Rider would update the `.en.Designer.cs` files occasionally. But yeah, removing the Designer files seems to work (as long as their corresponding class wasn't in use). Thanks!